# Telegram API. Get the text of the picture signature

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Prompt. How to get Caption from the picture sent to the bot?
I can not understand. Thank you.

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):
    try:

```
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    text = message.text
    vid_id = message.chat.first_name

    file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo)-1].file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

    src='/home/pi/test/'+file_info.file_path;
    with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
       new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    bot.reply_to(message,"Foto add") 
    img = open(src, 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(adminid, img)
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    callback_bad = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="KILL", callback_data='story[!!!]'+str(file_info.file_path))
    keyboard.add(callback_bad)
    bot.send_message(adminid,"Add: "+vid_id , reply_markup=keyboard)

except Exception as e:
    bot.send_message(adminid, e)
```